# Eloquent query if value in relationship isn't same as value in other relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have four models: `Item`, `Car`, `ItemLocation` and `Branch`.

An `Item` has a `Car` and a `ItemLocation` via a `person_id` and a `item_location_id` field in the DB.

A `Car` has a `branch_id` which links to `Branch`, and an `ItemLocation`  also has a `branch_id` in the same way.

What I want to do is to select all `Item`s where their `Cars`'s branch is not equal to their `ItemLocation`'s branch.

I tried this statement, though I knew that it wouldn't work:

```
Item::with('car','item_location')
    ->where('car.branch_id', '<>', 'item_location.branch_id')
    ->get();
```

I'm aware of [querying on relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations), but don't understand how to do that across relationships like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Querying relationships won't help you, since you want to compare values from separate tables. You need joins:

```php
$items = Item::select('items.*')
             ->join('item_locations as il', 'il.id', '=', 'items.item_location_id')
             ->join('cars', function ($j) {
                 $j->on('cars.person_id', '=', 'items.id')
                   ->on('cars.branch_id', '<>', 'il.branch_id');
             })
             ->get()
```

This will fetch all the `items` having both `cars` and `item_location` and matching your criteria. If you want to include also ones that don't have either of the relations, then use `leftJoins` instead and `whereNull('cars.id')`

ps. It's hard to read your question. Instead of describing these relationships, better simply show the tables with relevant fields.